# adding new elements to a div tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do some background animation using javascript that looks like rain(drops falling from top to bottom infinitely). But it isn't working. I can't figure out where is the problem.

```js
function add(){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.width = "1px";
  div.style.height = '7%';
  div.style.background = 'linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #ffffff 75%, #ffffff 100%)';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.animation = 'spin 4s infinite';
  div.style.transition =  'all 3s';

  var l = 10;

  for (var i;i<20;i=i+1){
    div.style.left = toString(l+10)+'px';
    div.style.animationDelay = toStrin(Math.random() * 10) + 's';
    document.getElementsClass("back").appendChild(div);
  }
}

window.onload = function(){
  add();
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;
}
@keyframes spin{
  0%{
    top: -20px;
  }
  100%{
    top:90%;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Trail</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="back"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I got stuck here for a long time please help!!!

Comment: How is your animation supposed to look like and what exactly does not work?

Comment: If you have a completely working code please post it as an snippet using the `<>` button. I've created it for you this time.

Comment: What is `document.getElementsClass("back")`

Comment: Other issue once you get that fixed is you are adjusting the same element's position over and over and appending the same element.

Comment: There's some basic javascript erros. var i not initialized, and not used. And isn't clear what sort animation you want to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You have many mistakes here.

1. You initialized `i` but default value not assigned
2. `document.getElementsClass("back").appendChild(div)` is wrong. use like this `document.getElementsByClassName("back")[0].appendChild(div);`
3. you have to use `(num).toString()`, not like the way you used

```js
function add(){


var l = 10;

for (var i=0;i<20;i=i+1){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
div.appendChild(node);
div.style.width = "1px";
div.style.height = '7%';
div.style.background = 'linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #ffffff 75%, #ffffff 100%)';
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.animation = 'spin 4s infinite';
div.style.transition =  'all 3s';
div.style.color = '#ffffff';
    div.style.left = (l+(i*10)).toString()+'px';
    div.style.animationDelay = (Math.random() * 10).toString() + 's';
    document.getElementById("back").appendChild(div);
}
}
window.onload = function(){
  add();
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;
}
@keyframes spin{
  0%{
    top: -20px;
  }
  100%{
    top:90%;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="back"></div>
```

Comment: Still has issues

Comment: can you explain the issues?

Comment: Read my second comment under the original post

Comment: OP wants to add a bunch of elements and have them animate at a different time. For loop makes no sense if it is just one.